# How to guarantee that JPanel fits with JFrame

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout

I am first adding some elements to a `JPanel` and then adding the `JPanel` to the contentPane of the `JFrame`. However, the elements I add to the JPanel are all not fitting inside the Jframe. How do I ensure that all elements inside the `JPanel` are visible inside the JFrame

Comment: You'll want to read the tutorials on the layout managers available so that you can get to know them quite well as they are the key to "fitting" and sizing your GUI appropriately. Then yes, call `pack()` as @kajacx states below (1+ to him).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try calling the pack() method on the frame after adding the panel, like

```
myFrame.add(myPanel);
myFrame.pack();
```

this should fit the frame's size to it's components.

Comment: I tried this but now my entire window is just the taskbar :(....cant see anything

Comment: strange, are you using any layout managers? Last time I used BorderLayout and pack() worked fine. True, i had only pre-defined components (buttons and labels) and no panels.

Comment: since you av only one jpanel inside a jframe content pane, trying using a box layout, or grid layout. it will fit right in.

Comment: He needs to read the layout manager tutorials as has been recommended more than 2 hours ago. Find them here: [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html).

Comment: @Programmer: If you're adding your own component(s) to the frame, you may need to override `getPreferredSize()` as discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7229662/230513).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels enough RTFM already! some of us need answers!

Comment: @randomstring: you think that there's an easy way to learn all of this stuff? Sorry to say but there are no short cuts, and the sooner you learn that and RTFM, the sooner you'll become a real programmer.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels dude, i just need to plot a few points today to debug something and then for the next couple of years i won't need to touch this again and perhaps for ever because the web browser is where the action is (don't bring up javafx please). if you think one should spend hours learning swing just to plot a few points on a one-off basis it is more of a reflection of how misguided your own programming priorities are. jeez.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels you are simply trolling around completely unhelpfully. everybody knows there are tutorials and manuals. we all have our domains of expertise where we have invested and it helps to not have everybody bear the significant fixed cost of learning everything.